# mysql trigger syntax error in maria db

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I was trying to make one trigger , so that i can check for any negative insertion of age .
I tried below query but its showing below error .

```
CREATE TRIGGER agecheck 
    BEFORE INSERT ON people
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    (CASE WHEN people.age  > 0 THEN  people.age ELSE 0 END )
END
```

ERROR CODE:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN people.age  > 0 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END )
>   END' at line 5

Am i doing anything wrong in the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The statement you have in your trigger is not a statement. It's just an expression. This is not a thing you can use as a statement by itself.

I'm just guessing at what you are trying to do: make sure `age` is not negative. You could probably do this by declaring the column as `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, but if you want to do it with a trigger:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.age = CASE WHEN NEW.age > 0 THEN NEW.age ELSE 0 END;
END
```

In a trigger, always reference the columns of the respective triggered row with `NEW.<columnname>` or `OLD.<columnname>`.

Another expression that works just as well:

```
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.age = GREATEST(NEW.age, 0);
END
```

There's no specific advantage for this alternative, I'm just showing another use of an expression.